# Delete records from table that are not in the file being inserted

Tags: sql-server, insert, merge

I have a Snaplogic pipeline that queries a web application every night and loads the data into a SQL Server table. I use the 'Update' snap to add new records or add any changes. The goal is that the database should mirror the web application (with a one day lag).

The Update seems to be working fine. The issue is, when a record is deleted in the web application, it isn't being deleted in the database. Does anyone have any ideas as to how to either delete a record in the target database when it's been deleted in the source application or flag the record in the database as 'deleted' in the source?

I thought perhaps I could write the daily data to a temp table and then do some form of merge or insert operation in the database. Or I could truncate the table in the database and rebuild it each day with the new data but as the data grows that's seems very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

> Or I could truncate the table in the database and rebuild it each day with the new data but as the data grows that's seems very inefficient.

Those are the ways.  "Trunc and load" is more efficient then "Stage and Merge" if you are "staging" all the rows that you want in the final table.